# use the same alias in main query and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, alias

```
SELECT t.id, x.*
FROM some_table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT x.id, sum(z.quantity)
    FROM other_table x
    INNER JOIN another_table y on y.id_x = x.id
    GROUP BY x.id
) x ON x.id = t.id
```

As you can see, I'm using the same alias `x` twice: once on the main query and again in the subquery.

Is that ok? Or that could be potencially problematic?

The results I'm getting are correct, but may be it was a fluke and I want to be sure.

Comment: I think its ok, at least in this case. But my question would be why would you use the same alias twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be fine as is, and should run.  The outer query won't "see" the alias `x` inside the subquery, it will just know about the result set from the entire subquery aliased as `x`.  That being said, from a code craft point of view, I usually avoid using the same alias in a query more than once, for several reasons.  If some other person is reading your query, that `x` was used in several places as an alias could throw them off.  In addition, should someone inherit and refactor your code, the alias reuse could also lead to a bug.